# Find subsystem of sys/fs/cgroup

Tags: operating-system, cgroups

Why am I unable to access the cgroup's filesystem as expected in Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) virtual machine? I can only see a few files instead of the specific directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgl95.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyztO.png)

Now I use virtual machine with Ubuntu 22.04 jammy jelly fish

Try to find cgroup's subsystem but I don't find this